# Get-AzureStorageContainer : The request is being throttled

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, throttling

What is the default throttling on this command?

My question is on how to throttle this command:

```
Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $item.context -ConcurrentTaskCount 2
```

Would -ConcurrentTaskCount 2 do the trick here? I know the default is 10.

My question on that hook, is as follows:
If I have a storage account with 52 containers and I set it to 2, does that mean it will make 26 get calls over time (that sounds bad), if I set it to 100 would that just mean one large call and one large return (sounds better but might actually make more calls because it can move through my list of resource groups faster)?

Or maybe it would be better to make the -ConcurrentTaskCount 100 and put a sleep of a few seconds in there.

Looking for suggestions thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, I don't think the error log is related with parameter. According to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestoragecontainer?view=azurermps-4.1.0).

This parameter can help reduce network connection problems in low bandwidth environments. I don't think it will cause your error log.

What it the vaule of `$item.context`? You had better check it. You could use the following commands and test again.

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <name> -StorageAccountKey <key>

Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $ctx -ConcurrentTaskCount 2
```